# Disabling an ASP.net textbox without actually disabling it?

Tags: asp.net, textbox

Within an ASP.Net application I have, there is a textbox that gets a date from a `CalendarExtender`. When the textbox is populated it checks that date with another date on the form and displays a `modalpopupextender` popup if the dates are wrong. However, I DO NOT want to allow user input into this textbox, so when I set the `ReadOnly` field to false and tried `Enabled` to false, it doesn't allow manual entry however it ALSO disabled the postback and will not call the `TextChanged` event to fire the `modalpopupextender`. 
So is there a way to disable manual entry and not set it to `ReadOnly`?

Comment: What does enabled = true and readonly=true yield?

Comment: enabled = true and readonly accomplish kinda the same thing, the both prohibit the user from entering anything into the field. That is what I want but doing so will disable the modalpopup extender

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out, simply enter onkeypress="return false;" within the HTML tag

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
<asp:textbox id="txt1" onfocus="blur()" runat="server"/>
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below properties in the tag of textbox

**onkeydown="return false" onpaste="return false"**

ex:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TillDate_TextBox" runat="server" onkeydown="return false" onpaste="return false"></asp:TextBox>
```

the first property block typing in textbox and the second property block pasting in it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the exact components you are using, however the usual way to accomplish things like this is the following. Have selecting the date on the calendar modify the value of a hidden form field.  This will restrict the user from editing the value directly.  Then create another element like a div or a span, and use javascript to update the span/div to the value selected on the calendar.