# How to prevent user from editing asp:TextBox directly?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a TextBox that holds a time value that a user can specify to view certain things. Only times ending in 0 or 5 are valid so I'm using a Jquery slider to let the user select what time they want to see.

Here's my TextBox:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TimeSelect" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" Text="" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here's the code editing it (this gets called by the slider's "change" callback):

```
            function OnSelectedSliceChanged(value) {
                var now = new Date();
                var currentTime = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
                currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() - currentTime.getMinutes() % 5);
                currentTime.setMilliseconds(0);
                currentTime.setSeconds(0);

                var millisecondsToSubtract = (<%=ViewState[MaxTicks]%> -value) * oneInterval;

                var newTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime() - millisecondsToSubtract);

                $("#TimeSelect").attr("value", Pad("" + newTime.getHours(), 2) + ":" + Pad("" + newTime.getMinutes(), 2));
            }
```

Right now, the slider successfully changes the time in the TextBox, but the user can still edit the text manually.

I tried to prevent user editing the TextBox directly by setting `ReadOnly = "true"`. However, that results in my slider not being able to edit the TextBox as well.

Is there a way to prevent the user from editing the TextBox but letting the code still edit it?

Comment: try ReadOnly = "true".

Comment: @djs yes I was going to mention that but I assume it's what he meant. After all, why would ReadOnly="False" stop the slider from working?

Comment: @djs oops typo! "true" prevents my slider from being able to edit my TextBox as well.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the ReadOnly flag to have any effect on the slider, or anything else that changes the code programmatically.  I thought it just prevented changes from input devices.  I could be mistaken, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TextBox.ReadOnly` property is different from the HTML `readonly` attribute. The former ignores any changes made on the client side. The latter prevents a user from changing the input, but allows script to do so.

Try this on the server side:

```
TimeSelect.Attributes["readonly"] = "readonly";
```

Or this on the client side:

```
$("#TimeSelect").prop("readonly", "readonly");
```

Of course, neither of these completely prevent a user from changing the textbox. You can edit the properties using the inspector, or even catch the request before it goes out the modify the values. Make sure you validate the values on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the ability to focus the textbox.

```
$("#TimeSelect").prop("disabled", true);
```

---

### Edit

To prevent the input from turning grey, or to apply new styles, add one or more classes using the CssClass attribute.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TimeSelect" runat="server" CssClass="time-textbox" BorderWidth="2px" Text="" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then style the class accordingly...

```
.time-textbox {background-color:white !important;}
```

Comment: thanks! that worked! =] Is there a way to prevent the text from turning gray though?

Answer (score 1):

These is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142156/disabling-an-asp-net-textbox-without-actually-disabling-it)

I prefer this:

```
<asp:textbox id="txt1" onfocus="blur()" runat="server"/>
```

rather than `OnKeyPress="false"` because it does not behave as we want if the user tries to copy and paste some text.